# Как передать с помощью Ajax куки или сессию, подскажите?

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Здравствуйте, первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. Вообщем такая ситуация, нужно удалить картинку с помощью ajax, все работает если убрать с php разработчика и с connect.php

```
 if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die('Ошибка 404');
```

Может я неправильно понял, но, по-моему, кажется, что ajax  не передает cooke или сессию не передает. Ну, ребята, не знаю, как еще назвать. Вообщем как передать с помощью Ajax куки или сессию, подскажите? Гуглил не нашел, может плохо гуглил.

Comment: Правильно задайте вопрос.

Куки передаются вместе с Ajax запросами по умолчанию.

Почитайте в php про функции define(), и defined()

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
цитата "Правильно задайте вопрос." - как еще по другому задать вопрос?

Comment: @benulima, например "AJAX: cookie, сессии".
Действительно, куки передаются вместе с AJAX-запросом. То, что вы пытаетесь имплементировать выглядит по-другому:
connect.php:

    <?php
    session_start();
    ...
    $_SESSION['include_check'] = true;
    ?>

use.php

    <?php
    session_start();
    ...
    if(!$_SESSION['include_check']){
         header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
         exit();
    }else{
         unset($_SESSION['include_check']);
         //действия
    }
    ?>

Comment: @bemulima, написав свой вопрос, прочитайте его от начала и до-конца, и решите, будет ли ваш вопрос понятен людям, которые понятия не имеют, над чем вы работаете.
Что вы имели ввиду под фразой: "все работает если убрать с php разработчика и с connect.php"? Я лично, ничего не понял.
К тому-же, не понятно, к чему тот кусок кода, что вы привели. Он не дает представления о происходящем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

функция [define](http://php.net/define) используется для задания глобальной константы в приложении, например, для того, чтобы скрипты могли "понять", как именно они вызываются, напрямую из браузера, или когда инклудятся в другой скрипт. Это делается при помощи функции [defined](http://php.net/defined).

Приведу пример.
У нас есть файл index.php, и файл cofig.php
Файл index.php у нас является входной точкой в приложение, внутри него происходит подключение файла config.php, в котором происходит инициализация некоторых данных.
В некоторых случаях необходимо запретить выполнение сценариев при прямых запросах к этим файлам.

index.php:

```
<?
echo "Hello! ";
define('INCLUDE_CHECK', true);
include "config.php";
echo "world"
```

config.php:

```
<?
if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK'))
   echo "disabled ";
else
   echo "enabled ";
```

Теперь при попытке выполнить файл index.php у вас будет выведено сообщение "Hello! enabled world", т.к., в index.php определена константа INCLUDE_CHECK А при попытке выполнить файл config.php, будет выведено слово "disabled", т.к. в нем никакие константы не определены.